# SUMIF/COUNTIF equivalent in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a statement that will basically do a COUNTIF in Access.  I have a field in my table that can either be 1, 2, or 3.  I want it to do the following:

```
Countif (strclosewhere = 1)
```

I also thought of doing a SUMIF by using the sum or count statement, just not sure of the syntax. I tried the following

```
Sum(IIf(strclosewhere=1,1,0))
```

However I get the error that it is too complex to evaluate.

Comment: Oddly, there appears to be no convenient question to dupe this to. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL View, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT Count(strclosewhere) AS Cnt
FROM Table
WHERE strclosewhere = 1;
```

Alternatively, use the domain aggregate function:

```
=DCount("*","Table","[strclosewhere]=1")
```

*(Both of these assume your table is just named `Table`. This is presumably not the case.)*

Comment: That won't work, because there are many other fields that have a straight sum.  This is just one field of about 30 that need to be summed up.  Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: @SASUSMC, you're gonna need to expand your original question for it to be answered, then. What's your intended query structure: single-row with multiple columns, grouped aggregates, or what?

Comment: @SASUSMC, it should also be noted that DCount can be used within queries, given the appropriate criteria.